# How to store the output of a step as an env_variable in github actions

Tags: github-actions

```
  - name: Set outputs
    id: vars
    run: |
      counter=$((${{ secrets.TEST_COUNTER }} + 1))
      echo "::set-output name=counter::$counter"
      echo "::set-output name=version_number::V${{ secrets.VERSION_NUMBER }}-beta-$counter"
```

This is part of my workflow.I need to store the value of version_number to an env variable.

I have applied the code:

```yaml
  - name: setup env variable
    run: echo "env variable is $APPLICATION_VERSION_NO "
    env:  
      APPLICATION_VERSION_NO: ${{ steps.vars.outputs.version_number }}
```

I need the env variable in frontend but when I try to access the env variable through frontend I am  getting the output like undefined version number. Could you please help?

Comment: Does it related to C#?

Comment: You are setting an output parameter, not an env. You have typos in your workflow. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable and https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter. You can lint your complete workflow with https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ and fix these typos.

Answer (score 1):

I have made changes to use GITHUB_OUTPUT instead of github env.

```
jobs:
  my_job:
    name: My Job
    runs-on: [xx]
    outputs:
      version_number: ${{ steps.vars.outputs.version_number }}
    steps:
      - name: set-output
        id: vars
        run: |
          counter=$((${{ secrets.TEST_COUNTER }} + 1))
          echo "counter=${counter}" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
          echo "version_number=V${{ secrets.VERSION_NUMBER }}-beta-$counter" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
        shell: bash

      - name: setup env variable
        run: echo "env variable is $APPLICATION_VERSION_NO "
        env:  
          APPLICATION_VERSION_NO: ${{ steps.vars.outputs.version_number }}
```

Comment: I need to store the version_number=V${{ secrets.VERSION_NUMBER }}-beta-${counter}
as an env variable without using $GITHUB_ENV

Comment: I have edited my changes, please try once

Comment: all you were missing is - outputting your variables